# Can Raspberry Pi survive outside temperatures?

Tags: temperature

I am making a raspberry pi outside security camera, but I am scared that my pi will not be able to survive my area harsh temperatures. I live in Illinois, so it gets pretty cold here. Does anyone know if my pi could survive in my weather 24/7? Also do I need a case to protect my pi outside?

Comment: `it gets pretty cold here` Some people find 10C pretty cold and others think that's tropical. I don't know Illinois, so maybe you can add a bit more detail to your question, such as the temperatures you are experiencing.

Comment: Welcome.  I realize the duplicate doesn't have an answer, but the question itself may be of use.  See also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/46708/5538 The official story here is 0C/32F.  WRT "Do I need a case?", I think it goes without saying that plugging in a credit card size PCB and leaving it in the rain/snow/etc. is a no-go.  So yes, you need a case or something to protect the board.  It is not waterproof.

Comment: Coldest temperatures are around 20 F and hot is around 110 F